# How to Auto Save <p> tag content using savy.js plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-plugins

I try to implement an autosave feature on the HTML page. so that when the user types anything it would store in local storage. For this, I am found the savy.js jquery plugin. when I using this plugin on the `<p>` tag or on `div` then savy.js not working but if use it on `input` and `text area` then it is successfully storing data into local storage.
I need to store user-edited content in local storage. I don't know much about savy.js plugin. why it is doing so. please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Auto Save</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
            <h3 class = "auto-save" id = "abc" contenteditable="true">Nitin Saini</h3>
                
<input type="text" id="xg" class="auto-save">
            <p class = "auto-save" id = "xyz" contenteditable="true">I am Engineer</p><br>            
            <textarea name="" id="" rows="8" cols="80" class="auto-save"></textarea>
           
    </div>


</body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="savy.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.auto-save').savy('load',function(){
        console.log("All data from savy are loaded");

    });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Some more info on the "savy.js" would help.  Do you have a link to the documentation / *official* website?

Comment: A quick look at [a potential source](https://github.com/medabida/savy/blob/master/savy.js) shows that you could replicate the `if($(this).is("input")` section and change `this.value` to `this.innerText`

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, I didn't get what you are trying to say. please elaborate.

Comment: Take the source of savy.js.   Look at it.  It's separated into sections based on the element type, `radio`/`checkbox`/`input`/`select`.   The `input` is closest to contenteditable div/p.  Copy those *ten* lines.  Change the `if` to match `contenteditable`.  Change the bit that reads the value from `this.value` to `this.innerText`.  Save to your website.

Comment: @freedomn-m I did what you suggest copy those 10 line and copied  it after elseif of` input`  and make the change as you said `elseif($(this).is("p"))if(localStorage.getItem(sv+this.id)){ this.innerText = localStorage.getItem(sv+this.id); }$(this).on( 'focus', function(){
 var intervalDuration = 500,interval = setInterval( () => { localStorage.setItem(sv+this.id, this.value);if(!$(this).is(":focus")) clearInterval(interval);   }, intervalDuration ); }); }`  now it makes key in local storage i.e storing content when I refresh the page it didn't set the element just showing `undefined`.

Comment: @freedomn-m please reply, if I am doing any mistake. I really need to implement this It is necessary for my project.